# Firebase object with sub-objects to Java class

Tags: java, android, firebase, class, firebase-realtime-database

[I am trying to read from relatime database the following object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7S5z.png)

The JSON exported from Firebase is this:

```
"categorias" : {
    "Telas de Hogar" : {
      "descripcion" : "",
      "estado" : "invisible",
      "nombre" : "Telas de Hogar",
      "paginas" : {
        "Loneta" : {
          "descripcion" : "",
          "estado" : "invisible",
          "nombre" : "Loneta"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The current class:

```
package com.example.tejidospulido_app.Model.Classes;
import java.util.Map;

public class Category {
    private String nombre;
    private String descripcion;
    private String estado;
    private Map<String, String> productos;
    private Map<String, Page> paginas;

    public Category(){}

    public Category(String name) {
        this.nombre = "";
        this.descripcion = "";
        this.estado = "";
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getProductos() {
        return this.productos;
    }

    public void setProductos(Map<String, String> productos) {
        this.productos = productos;
    }

    public Map<String, Page> getPaginas() {
        return this.paginas;
    }

    public void setPaginas(Map<String, Page> pages) {
        this.paginas = paginas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nombre;
    }
}
```

I have managed to read the object with its attributes but when I want to read the **paginas** and the **productos**, it returns me null in **paginas** and thi error in **productos**:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertString(CustomClassMapper.java:426)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:217)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:179)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToParameterizedType(CustomClassMapper.java:265)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:177)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:593)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
        at com.example.tejidospulido_app.Vista.MenuFragment$2.onDataChange(MenuFragment.java:95)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:189)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I have searched and read from different sources and from what I understand I should use Maps, but the truth is, I don't know how to do it ...

This is the code of the reading, and if I debug its followed by an image of the debug result.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("categorias").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Category c = snapshot.getValue(Category.class);
            list.add(c);
        }
        AdapterCategories adapter = new AdapterCategories(list);
        recycleView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: What does the `Page` class look like?

Comment: Also: please study [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as I doubt the `descripcion`, `estado` and `nombre` properties are needed to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution As You Mentioned Is Maps, I Will Help You To Imagine That
Let's Start from the simple to complex

Before You Read This Keep in mind that the map is just an object storing key values Like JSON Storing a Key Value

First, This Inner Pagena Object In Json Looks Like

```
"Loneta" : {
          "descripcion" : "",
          "estado" : "invisible",
          "nombre" : "Loneta"
        }
```

When You Want To represent that using map it will be

```
Map<String,String> Loneta = new HashMap();
Loneta.put("descripcion" , "");
Loneta.put("estado" , "invisible");
Loneta.put("nombre" , "Loneta");
```

So The Loneta Object in JSON Is Now A Map Note That The Key "Loneta" is the map variable name

To Retrieve something from it

```
String descripcion = Loneta.get("descripcion");
```

Now Lets' Get Deeper

```
"Telas de Hogar" : {
      "descripcion" : "",
      "estado" : "invisible",
      "nombre" : "Telas de Hogar",
      "paginas" : {
        "Loneta" : {
          "descripcion" : "",
          "estado" : "invisible",
          "nombre" : "Loneta"
        }
      }
    }
```

"Telas de Hogar" Can Be Represented As Map

We Will Use The Key "Telas de Hogar" As The Variable Name Of The Map
Let's Create this Map

```
Map<String,String> Telas_de_Hogar = new HashMap();
Telas_de_Hogar.put("descripcion" , "");
Telas_de_Hogar.put("estado" , "invisible");
Telas_de_Hogar.put("nombre" , "Telas de Hogar");
```

When It Comes To "paginas" Key, Take A Minute And Think In That
"paginas" is A Key So It Will Be Map Variable Name

```
Map<String,String> paginas= new HashMap();
```

Think Again What is should be inside This Map

We Have A Key "Loneta" And It's Values, So We Need A Loneta Map , Remember That We Created it?

So Put it in "paginas" But Here We Need Some Changes
pagins is a map of string key and map value containing maps of string string
So We Need To Change The Declaration of it TO

```
Map<String, Map<String,String>> pagins = new HashMap();    
paginas.put("Loneta", Loneta);
```

"Loneta" Is The Key And Loneta is The Map Object Reference

Put paginas Map inside Telas_de_Hogar Map

```
Telas_de_Hogar.put("paginas", paginas)
```

Again "paginas" Is The Key And paginas is The Map Object Reference

Finally The Top Level Key "categorias" Which Containing The Values Of Telas_de_Hogar Map
Let's Create it

```
Map<String,String> categorias= new HashMap();
categorias.put("Telas de Hogar", Telas_de_Hogar);
```

I Hope My Answer Help You

**UPDATE:**

If You Want To Use .getValue(YourClass.class);
Change that in your Category Class

```
private Map<String, String> productos;
```

TO

```
private Map<String, Map<String, String> productos;
```

Explaination:
The "Pagins" is A Map Of Key String And Map Value of String String

See upove we put Lonita as map in pagins map

```
"paginas" : {
        "Loneta" : {
          "descripcion" : "",
          "estado" : "invisible",
          "nombre" : "Loneta"
        }
```

Comment: Okey, I understand what you say, and I am really grateful to you, but I am trying tu use the getValue(Class) option that convert the JSON object from firebase to my class.

Comment: Am Really Sorry For This Misunderstanding I Will Update My Answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to thank [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) and [Hussien Fahmy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15262615/hussien-fahmy), they helped me a lot with their answares.

To achive me goal, I have created two classes, the Page.class and the ProductReference.class. Then I have referenced them in the Category.class using Map.

Here are the three classes:

```
public class Category {
    private String nombre;
    private String descripcion;
    private String estado;
    private Map<String, ProductReference> productos;
    private Map<String, Page> paginas;

    public Category(){}

    public Category(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.descripcion = "";
        this.estado = "";
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public Map<String, ProductReference> getProductos() {
        return this.productos;
    }

    public void setProductos(Map<String, ProductReference> productos) {
        this.productos = productos;
    }

    public Map<String, Page> getPaginas() {
        return this.paginas;
    }

    public void setPaginas(Map<String, Page> paginas) {
        this.paginas = paginas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nombre;
    }
}
```

```
public class Page {
    private String nombre;
    private String descripcion;
    private String estado;
    private Map<String, ProductReference> productos;

    public Page() {
    }

    public Page(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.descripcion = "";
        this.estado = "";
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public Map<String, ProductReference> getProductos() {
        return this.productos;
    }

    public void setProductos(Map<String, ProductReference> productos) {
        this.productos = productos;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nombre;
    }
}
```

```
public class ProductReference {
    private String numero;

    public ProductReference(){}

    public ProductReference(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return numero;
    }
}
```

And this is the result:
[image]